# html absolute position inside absolute

Tags: html, css

Quick Example,

html,

```
<div class="firstdiv">
    firstdiv
    <div class="seconddiv">
        seconddiv
    </div>
</div>
```

css,

```
.firstdiv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:pink;
}
.seconddiv{
    position:absolute;
}
```

fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/32pj4y16/

I want the `seconddiv` x,y axis, not to be related to `firstdiv`.

I want the `seconddiv`, starting from the x: 0px, y:0px;

but in here, it recognize the (0,0) is starting at the firstdiv part.

Comment: so you want `seconddiv` to move out of `firstdiv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make them move freely do this[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32pj4y16/2/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="firstdiv">
    firstdiv

    </div>
    <div class="seconddiv">
        seconddiv
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can make container relative or absolute according to your requirement and its easier to set positions in this way

Comment: awesome :) this is want i wanted

Answer (score 1):

An element with `position: absolute` will use the its closest positioned ancestor to determine its own position. So in your case, `.seconddiv` will always use `.firstdiv` as its context for positioning.

What you can do is add `top：-100px` and `left: -100px` to `.seconddiv`, making it move to the top left, out of `.firstdiv`.

[Here's how it'd work, based on your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/32pj4y16/1/)

Comment: consider using em or percentages - pixels are hard to compensate for across the array of devices in the market

Comment: @Canna - then write some simple math to determine your desired location and attach it to the window.resize event

Answer (score 1):

Actually It is possible with scripting.

If you don't want to alter ur structure go with this :)

Here are the steps to achieve what you want:

1. get the top and left position values of seconddiv
2. subtract the top and left values of seconddiv from firstdiv top and left values
3. set the top and left position values of seconddiv

Example:

1. consider secondTop=50px; ( top value of seconddiv ), secondLeft=50px; (left value of seconddiv)
2. from ur code snippet firstTop=100px and firstLeft=100px
    So let x=50-100; ( secondLeft-firstLeft ) y=50-100; ( secondTop-firstTop)
3. set 'x' value as 'left' value and 'y' value as 'top' value of seconddiv

JSBIN Example:
http://jsbin.com/hofalicohisu/1/edit

Comment: great. i like this too

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify position for your seconddiv. Try this:

```
.seconddiv{
   position:absolute;
   top:-100px;
   left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: i assume OP wants the inner div to break out of outer div!! :)

Comment: this way it wont break out...firstdiv will close second, so you would need negative margins!

Comment: @NoobEditor Ohh..For that you can specify negative top and left postion. I updated the answer. Check it, now it will break out of outer div.